# SharePoint List - Color on cell text menu

Tags: 2013, javascript, custom-list

I have a SharePoint list where I have code to change color on a cell based on the field. It works but when I change to the second page of the list, the code does not work.

First page :

[image]

Second page :

[image]

My code, I  think it's `$(document).ready` doesn't work... :

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Réalisé')");
$Text.css("background-color", "#4DD17E");
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Maîtrisé')");
$Text.css("background-color", "#E59B2C");
$Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('A risque')");
$Text.css("background-color", "#E52C2C");
$Text.css("color", "white");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Or if you have other solutions to offer me, I am a taker :)

Comment: search for JSLink in SharePoint 2013 or Client Side Rendering (CSR)

Comment: I have already search for topics on this type without success :(

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/list-column-highlight-sharepoint-2013

Comment: https://olafd.wordpress.com/2013/12/01/colored-output-in-list-view-with-jslink/

Comment: **ALWAYS** use the Chrome Browser with the WYSIWIG CSR editor [**Cisar**](http://365csi.nl/cisar) It is the best thing since sliced bread

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS link option to render Client side. you copy the below script in java script file. upload to a document library.
In list view Webpart Propeorties => JS link => you give this JS file reference so that it render the view. you can add multiple fields and switch cases as i shown one status field in the code

```
function registerRenderer() {

// Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render 
var priorityFiledContext = {};
priorityFiledContext.Templates = {};
priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
    // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View
    "Status": { "View": priorityFiledTemplate }
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext);

}

// This function provides the rendering logic for list view
function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) {

    var status = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];

    // Return html element with appropriate color based on priority value
    switch (status) {
        case "Réalisé":
            return "<span style='backgroundColor:#4DD17E;'>" + status + "</span>";
            break;
        case "Maîtrisé":
            return "<span style='backgroundColor:#E59B2C;'>" + status + "</span>";
            break;
        case "A risque":
            return "<span style='backgroundColor:#E52C2C;'>" + status + "</span>";
break;

    }
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');
```

Comment: Thank you but Sorry, I did not succeed ... it doesn't work ... :(

Comment: Are you getting any javascript error by using above script ?

Comment: It works perfectly for me. May be check clienttemplates.js file reference missing. let me know what error coming in browser console.

Comment: SCRIPT1002: Erreur de syntaxe

Comment: I forgot something I think ...

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code provided by Suresh

```
function registerRenderer() {

// Create object that have the context information about the field that we  want to change it's output render 
var priorityFiledContext = {};
priorityFiledContext.Templates = {};
priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
// Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View
"Statut": { "View": priorityFiledTemplate }
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext);

}
// This function provides the rendering logic for list view

function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) {

var status = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
// Return html element with appropriate color based on priority value
switch (status) {
    case "None":
        return '<span style="background-color:#4DD17E;">' + status + '</span>';
        break;
    case "Started":
        return '<span style="background-color:#2DD15A;">' + status + '</span>';
        break;
    case "Completed":
        return '<span style="background-color:#6DD12C;">' + status + '</span>';
        break;

}
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

that's was my Solution:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>

var tableHeader = null;

window.onload = function () {
    var table = $('.ms-listviewtable')[0];
    tableHeader = $(table).find("thead")[0];

    handleStatusColumn('Status');   
}

function handleStatusColumn(columnTitle){
    colorCellsInSpecificColumn(columnTitle, findCells('O'), '#f08080');     
    colorCellsInSpecificColumn(columnTitle, findCells('IP'), '#d8bfd8');    
    colorCellsInSpecificColumn(columnTitle, findCells('C'), '#c2d633');     
}



function findCells(type){
    return $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().trim() === type;
    })
}

function colorCellsInSpecificColumn(column, cellElement, colorHex){
    $.each(cellElement, function( index, value ) {
        var cellIndex = cellElement[index].cellIndex;
        //Return column label base on index of cell
        var columnLabel = returnLabelOfColumn(cellIndex);
        if(columnLabel === column){
            $(cellElement[index]).css("background-color", colorHex);
        }
    });     
}

function returnLabelOfColumn(cellIndex){
    var cellColumnHeader = $(tableHeader).find('th')[cellIndex];
    var headerLabel = $(cellColumnHeader).text().trim();
    return headerLabel 
}




 </script>
```

****enjoy** ;)!!**