# List Column Highlight in Sharepoint 2013 for IE11 and Edge Browsers

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, custom-list

I used the code suggested in this previous post ([List Column Highlight Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/list-column-highlight-sharepoint-2013/257419#257419)), and it works fine in *Chrome* and *firefox*, however it does not seem to work in *IE11* or Edge browsers. Is there something I need to add to the code below to allow the `highlighted rows` to show in *IE11* and *Edge* as well?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

       var statusColors =  {
          'Yes' : '#F3F31580' ,
          'No' : '#FFFFFF'
       };

       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var status = rows[i]["EventChangePending"];
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
          row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
       }
     }
   }); 

});
</script>
```

Thanks,

Albert

Answer (score 2):

Your jslink code is fine. The problem is in the color notation that you are trying to set to the background of the row. Neither IE nor Edge support [the notation with included opacity](https://caniuse.com/#search=hex).

If you change this part `'Yes' : '#F3F31580'`  to this `'Yes' : '#F3F315'` it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you really want to specify opacity, you can use RGBA, which is supported by edge and IE (8+ I believe). In RGBA, your color would be "rgba(243, 243, 21, 0.5)"